# Implementing UIScrollView Inside CollectionViewcell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am using a collectionViewCell where I have a scrollView>view>imageview, which means a view is embedded inside scrollView and an imageView is embedded inside the view. I have set `CollectionViewCell` class as scrollView Delegate and using the function `viewForZooming` so when the user taps it will zoom with maximum scale but nothing happens. Following is my code for `CollectionViewCell` class:

```
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    
    var imageView: UIImageView = {
        var myImageView = UIImageView()
        myImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        return myImageView
    }()
    
    var scrollView: UIScrollView = UIScrollView()
    var scrollContentView: UIView = UIView()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.addSubview(scrollContentView)
        scrollContentView.addSubview(imageView)
        scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
        
        scrollView.delegate = self
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 5.0
        
        let constraints = [
            // Scroll View Constraints
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.topAnchor,constant: 0.0),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.bottomAnchor,constant: 0.0),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.trailingAnchor,constant: 0.0),
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.leadingAnchor,constant: 0.0),
            
            // scrollContentView Constraints
            scrollContentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.topAnchor,constant: 0.0),
            scrollContentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.bottomAnchor,constant: 0.0),
            scrollContentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.trailingAnchor,constant: 0.0),
            scrollContentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.leadingAnchor,constant: 0.0),
            scrollContentView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.heightAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            scrollContentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.widthAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            // ImageView Constraints
            imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollContentView.topAnchor,constant: 0.0),
            imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollContentView.bottomAnchor,constant: 0.0),
            imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollContentView.trailingAnchor,constant: 0.0),
            imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollContentView.leadingAnchor,constant: 0.0)
        ]
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    public func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return imageView
    }
}
```

The code I am using in CollectionViewClass:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    
    cell.imageView.image =  selectedImage[indexPath.item]
    
    cell.scrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: cell.imageView.image!.size.width, height: cell.imageView.image!.size.height)
    cell.scrollContentView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: cell.scrollView.frame.width, height: cell.scrollView.frame.height)
    cell.imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: cell.frame.width  , height: cell.frame.height)
    
    cell.scrollView.clipsToBounds = true
    cell.scrollContentView.clipsToBounds = true
    cell.imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    
    cell.backgroundColor = .black
    
    return cell
}
```

I saw a YouTube tutorial guy was doing the same except it wasn't for collectionViewCell.
I think my scrollView is not even responding to touches.

Comment: You set image size to cell size so it can not scroll. And you do not set scrollview contentSize.

Comment: if I set the image size bigger than the cell size it expands outside the cell.

Comment: Did you try to set scrollView.contentSize to image size ?

Comment: yes tried many things by now also tried to get the touch events of scrollView with the following functions pangesture recognizer state which always prints default and  willbeginscrolling